# How to use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in Haxe?

Tags: geolocation, haxe

Maybe somebody can tell me how I will use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in Haxe.
In JavaScript this method needs 2 callback functions (success/error) and an option object. 
In the Haxe version of this method, the successCallback is typed as Position and the errorCallback is typed as PositionError. 
How do I use getCurrentPosition method in Haxe?

Answer (score 1):

> In the Haxe version of this method, the successCallback is typed as Position and the errorCallback is typed as PositionError.

This is inaccurate. The [documentation states](http://api.haxe.org/js/html/Geolocation.html):

- `successCallback:Position ‑> Void`
  this must be a callback accepting one argument of type `Position`
- `?errorCallback:PositionError ‑> Void`
  this is an optional callback acception one argument of type `PositionError`
- `?options:PositionOptions`
  these are optional `PositionOptions`

Here's a runnable example: http://try.haxe.org/#5EE17